# LIKE with trailing wildcard in Postgres doesn't use the index when the prefix is a result of a subquery

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, sql-like

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE test(id bigint primary key, path varchar);
```

with the additional index on path column

```
CREATE INDEX test_path_idx ON test(path varchar_pattern_ops);
```

With the query like this

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE path LIKE 'prefix%';
```

the index on path is used. It's still used with

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE path LIKE 'prefix' || '%';

Index Only Scan using test_path_idx on test  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=511)
  Index Cond: ((path ~>=~ 'prefix'::text) AND (path ~<~ 'prefiy'::text))
  Filter: ((path)::text ~~ 'prefix%'::text)
```

However, if the prefix is a result of a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE path LIKE (SELECT 'prefix')::varchar || '%';

Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.01..359.93 rows=20 width=511)
  Filter: ((path)::text ~~ ((($0)::character varying)::text || '%'::text))
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32)
```

the index is not used. Of course, in reality the subquery is more complicated but the above suffices to make the optimizer "ignore" the index.

I assume it happens because the optimizer cannot be sure there are no wildcards in the subquery result so it takes the "worst case" path. Is there a way to optimize this? Unfortunately, executing the inner select in a separate query and plugging in the result is not an option.

P.S. I have tested this on 9.6.

Comment: Please include the actual query.

Comment: I have simplified the example (after looking for the root cause for a long time) and as far as I could understand, the actual query doesn't matter. One can use e.g. "SELECT path FROM test WHERE id = 5" but it makes no difference.

Comment: I have added the execution plans to the question to demonstrate what happens

Comment: I've seen this problem before and I don't know any way to convince the DBMS that the selected string does not start with an ampersand. Only if you already know what the string starts with, you can do something like `select * from test where path like 'abc%' and path like (select x from y where ...)`, but this is an unlikely scenario.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that's a very interesting direction! Thank you!! In the current design of the table I couldn't know the prefix but I can change the design a bit to "know it". What is remarkable is that the condition has to be `WHERE path like '<known-prefix>%' AND path like '<known-prefix>' || (select ...) || '%'` ! Removing the seemingly redundant first part makes the query fall back to seq scan again!

Comment: I presume the `SELECT x FROM y WHERE...)` somehow can be rewritten into a `JOIN` in which you could then use `AND Left(path), Length(prefix)) = prefix` (or something along those lines). That is off course assuming that `Left(path, Len('prefix')) = 'prefix'` is index-aware off course.